# Relationship between BPM (tempo) and setting a timer interval.

Tags: computer-science, relations, linear-programming, ratio

I am currently working on a drum sequencer program in C#. I want the user to be able to control the tempo via a trackbar. I am using a timer to control a progressbar and to trigger soundplayer events.

The timer's interval is 100 ms, thus I have the progressbar reset at max (default max value of 80 for a total duration of 8 seconds). By default, the value of the trackbar is at 120 bpm.

The trackbar ranges from 90 to 150. I have 4 bars at 120 BPM by default, which has a total duration of 8 seconds.

I having been scratching my head for sometime about the math for this. I have concluded that at:

Tempo = 90: Timer Interval = 125, thus a total time of 10,000 milliseconds.
Tempo = 120: Timer Interval = 100, thus a total time of 8,000 milliseconds.
Tempo = 150: Timer Interval = 75, thus a total time of 6,000 milliseconds.

So to me it appears like a linear relationship, for which I should multiply the trackbar value by something to change the timer interval.

**But WHAT???**

I calculated the ratios between interval and BPM, but it did not get me any further in understanding the relationship. They are as follows:

125/90 = 1.83
120/100 = 0.83
150/75 = 0.5

**ANSWERS to comments:**
The trackbar is indeed setting the BPM. There are a total of 16 beats (4 bars with 4 beats).

I started out knowing that at 120 BPM these 16 beats will play for a total duration of 8 seconds because to convert BPM to milliseconds, the equation is 60,000 / BPM = MS.

Why 60,000?  There are 60 seconds in a minute, and 1,000 MS in a second.  So, 60 * 1,000 = 60,000. 60,000 divided by 120BPM = 500 milliseconds (.5 seconds)

500MS * 4 beats per measure = 2,000MS or 2 seconds per measure.

2 seconds * 4 measures = 8 seconds.

So based on that, I concluded (maybe incorrectly) that if I reduce the tempo by twenty five percent (value of 90) then the interval should increase by 25% (value of 125), thus increasing the total duration by 25% which is 10,000ms.

Hope this clarifies things.

Thanks for looking, I truly appreciate any help/direction on this problem!!!

Comment: This is extremely confusing and no clear question is asked.  It seems the trackbar is setting beats per minute.  How many beats in a bar?  How should we know that tempo 90 and timer interval 125 results in 10,000 milliseconds?  What are inputs and what are outputs?

Comment: Attempted to answer above question in an edit due to length.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that at $120$ BPM you will have each beat being $0.5$ seconds and $16$ beats will take $8$ seconds.  If you reduce the beat rate to $90$ BPM, each beat will be $\frac {60}{90}=\frac 23$ seconds and $16$ beats will take $16 \cdot \frac 23\approx 10.667$ seconds.  A reduction in BPM of $25\%$ does not increase the time by $25\%$, it increases it by $\frac 13 \approx 33.333\%$.  Is that what is confusing you?

Comment: This helps a lot! Sorry if I weirdly phrased my question and thank you so much for your help! I'm still in the process of figuring out what to multiply the timer interval by to make this work.But understanding this is a good start!